# Workflow for developing and distributing web-components

Tags: git, gulp, polymer, bower, web-component

I'm currently developing web-components. I'm transpiling them with Babel (using Gulp) before I can use them.
Currently I maintain two repositories:

1. Repository with the source-files
2. Repository with transpiled files for distribution via bower

It's tedious to distribute my components with this setup.

If I'd put them in the same repository and copy the transpiled files to the root folder I'd always have two copies of the same source-files and would distribute unnecessary files.

Do you have any ideas how I can improve my workflow of developing and distributing my web-components?

**Note:** I have to use git to distribute my components since I don't want to publish them to the public registry and also don't want to set up a private registry

Comment: Perhaps Grunt? (http://gruntjs.com/) It sounds like you need some kind of automation process for distribution.

Comment: Have separate `/src` and `/dist` folders, and in your `bower.json` file set `"ignore": ["/src"]`.